¿Como puedo conservar las hojas de un DataFrame?
Tengo un archivo xlsx que convierto a un dataframe, pero este archivo tiene varias hojas.
df_xlsx = pd.read_excel(archivo_xlsx, sheet_name=nombre_hoja, dtype=str)

Al realizar un merge de un frame_sql con el frame xlsx de una hoja en específico y guardarlo se pierden las demás hojas.
df_resultado = pd.merge(df_xlsx, frame_sql(), left_on=cuenta_xlsx, right_on='cuenta_sql', how='outer',
                        indicator=True)
df_resultado['Coincide'] = df_resultado['_merge'] == 'both'
df_resultado.to_excel('df_resultado_compare.xlsx')

¿Existe alguna manera de que esas hojas se conserven?,y guardar el resultado de mi merge en una hoja nueva.
